# openCV: Extracting cells fro the table

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have such an image and I want to extract cells from it.

[image]

Cell:

[image]

My simple code:

```
cell_size = image.shape[0] / 9, image.shape[1] / 9
digits = []
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        cell = image[int(i * cell_size[1]):int((i + 1) * cell_size[1]), int(j * cell_size[0]):int((j + 1) * cell_size[0])]
        digits.append(cell)
```

My idea was that usually the cells in the table are the same size. But in that picture above, it's not. So I should split table by lines. How to do that? Please, help me.

Comment: Invert the image so that the cells are white with black letters. Then find contours and the bounding box. Then crop each bounding box to get the numeral in the input.

Comment: assuming you have *contours*: cells have four corners (approxPolyDP). figure out a cell's directions, then associate neighbors to each direction, any way you like (estimate center of neighbor, use Nearest Neighbor query to find closest cell to that position)